# How to convert a list into a required dictionary format

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7

Input is given as  `a = "test1,test2,test3,test4,...etc"`

I want the output like below:

```
b={"test1":"test1","test2":"test2","test3":"test3",..etc}
```

Please let me know how can I do this.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? What problems did you encounter? What is `a`? Is it a string?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: a wild guess: it's a tuple?

Comment: @Kimvais: perhaps, but the example output is given as string values `test1`, `test2`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An addition to Martijn Pieters' [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13952631/1125413):

The dict comprehension only works with Python versions >= 2.7. For earlier versions of Python, you can create 2-valued tuples and pass them to the `dict()` function:

```
dict((item, item) for item in a.split(','))
```

And, finally, to mention this option as well, this would be the long way:

```
d = {} # alternatively, d = dict()
for item in a.split(','):
    d[item] = item
```

Answer (score 6):

To create a dictionary in a loop, use a dict comprehension.

Assuming that your `a` variable is a string with comma-separated values, the following would work:

```
{v: v for v in a.split(',')}
```

where we use each value in the comma-separated list as both key and value for the resulting dictionary.

The `{k: v ...}` dict comprehension was added in Python 2.7 and 3.0, in earlier python versions generate 2-value tuples instead:

```
dict((v, v) for v in a.split(','))
```

Comment: and if it's not a string, but a list or tuple, then just `{v: v for v in a}`

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning about variable 'a' , its a string. @martijn Pieters, thanks for the answer ,it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
tmp = a.split(",")
b = dict(zip(tmp,tmp))
```